# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint

Tags: sql

I am getting

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.

I guess there is problem in ",(100 * d.HIER) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.DP_ISLKOD,e.DP_KOD) as HIER"  how can solve this?

```
WITH DEPT (DP_USTISL,DP_USTKOD,DP_ISLKOD,DP_KOD,HIER, Level)
   AS ( 
   SELECT e.DP_USTISL
           ,e.DP_USTKOD
           ,e.DP_ISLKOD
           ,e.DP_KOD
           ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.DP_ISLKOD,e.DP_KOD)) AS HIER
           ,0 AS Level
   FROM  H_DEPLOG AS e
   WHERE
        (((RTRIM('01      ') = '' OR RTRIM('01      ') = '-') AND 
                 ((e.DP_USTISL IS NULL OR e.DP_USTKOD IS NULL) OR 
                  (e.DP_USTISL = e.DP_ISLKOD AND e.DP_USTKOD = e.DP_KOD)
                  )) OR
           ((RTRIM('0000') != '' AND RTRIM('0000') != '-' AND e.DP_ISLKOD='0000') AND 
                  ( (RTRIM('10000000') != '' AND RTRIM('10000000') != '-' AND e.DP_KOD='10000000') OR
                    ((RTRIM('10000000') = '' OR RTRIM('10000000') = '-' ) AND 
                        (e.DP_USTKOD IS NULL OR e.DP_USTKOD = e.DP_KOD OR e.DP_USTISL != e.DP_ISLKOD) 
                              )
                       )
           )
         ) AND 
              GETDATE() BETWEEN e.ilktrh AND ISNULL(e.sontrh,CONVERT(DATETIME,'99991231',112))
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.DP_USTISL
           ,e.DP_USTKOD
           ,e.DP_ISLKOD
           ,e.DP_KOD
           ,(100 * d.HIER) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.DP_ISLKOD,e.DP_KOD) as HIER --??
           ,Level + 1
   FROM  DEPT AS d
         INNER JOIN H_DEPT AS e ON e.DP_USTISL=d.DP_ISLKOD AND e.DP_USTKOD=d.DP_KOD AND 
                  --  GETDATE() BETWEEN e.ilktrh AND ISNULL(e.sontrh,CONVERT(DATETIME,'99991231',112)) AND
                   (0 = 0 OR e.DP_ISLKOD=d.DP_ISLKOD)
   WHERE (Level < 0 OR 0 = 0) AND NOT (E.DP_USTISL=E.DP_ISLKOD AND E.DP_USTKOD=E.DP_KOD)
   )
   SELECT TOP 374 * FROM DEPT
```

Comment: what's the possible max value for d.HIER?

Comment: Actually i do not know but when i select top 373 there is no problem and max value is for HIER is 1013002090101010102. I think top 374 is more than this.

Comment: What database is this?

Comment: `HIER` value of `1013002090101010102` means Level 0 was `1`, Level 1 was `1 01`, Level 2 was `1 01 30`, ... and Level 9 is `1 01 30 02 09 01 01 01 01 02`. At 10 levels, the value is 19 digits long, and if your hierarchy is even deeper than that, the numeric value will grown very big. Maybe you should re-think this.

Comment: What database is this? Oracle? Microsoft? PostgreSQL? MySQL? ...

Comment: Db is Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max value of bigint is 9223372036854775807 but (1013002090101010102*100) is way too high than highest value of bigint. That's why you are getting this error. You can convert bigint to decimal(38,0) to get rid of this error. Please try this:

```
           WITH DEPT (DP_USTISL,DP_USTKOD,DP_ISLKOD,DP_KOD,HIER, Level)
   AS ( 
   SELECT e.DP_USTISL
           ,e.DP_USTKOD
           ,e.DP_ISLKOD
           ,e.DP_KOD
           ,cast((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.DP_ISLKOD,e.DP_KOD)) as decimal (38, 0)) AS HIER
           ,0 AS Level
   FROM  H_DEPLOG AS e
   WHERE
        (((RTRIM('01      ') = '' OR RTRIM('01      ') = '-') AND 
                 ((e.DP_USTISL IS NULL OR e.DP_USTKOD IS NULL) OR 
                  (e.DP_USTISL = e.DP_ISLKOD AND e.DP_USTKOD = e.DP_KOD)
                  )) OR
           ((RTRIM('0000') != '' AND RTRIM('0000') != '-' AND e.DP_ISLKOD='0000') AND 
                  ( (RTRIM('10000000') != '' AND RTRIM('10000000') != '-' AND e.DP_KOD='10000000') OR
                    ((RTRIM('10000000') = '' OR RTRIM('10000000') = '-' ) AND 
                        (e.DP_USTKOD IS NULL OR e.DP_USTKOD = e.DP_KOD OR e.DP_USTISL != e.DP_ISLKOD) 
                              )
                       )
           )
         ) AND 
              GETDATE() BETWEEN e.ilktrh AND ISNULL(e.sontrh,CONVERT(DATETIME,'99991231',112))
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.DP_USTISL
           ,e.DP_USTKOD
           ,e.DP_ISLKOD
           ,e.DP_KOD
           ,(100 * cast(d.HIER as decimal (38, 0))) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.DP_ISLKOD,e.DP_KOD) as HIER --??
           ,Level + 1
   FROM  DEPT AS d
         INNER JOIN H_DEPT AS e ON e.DP_USTISL=d.DP_ISLKOD AND e.DP_USTKOD=d.DP_KOD AND 
                  --  GETDATE() BETWEEN e.ilktrh AND ISNULL(e.sontrh,CONVERT(DATETIME,'99991231',112)) AND
                   (0 = 0 OR e.DP_ISLKOD=d.DP_ISLKOD)
   WHERE (Level < 0 OR 0 = 0) AND NOT (E.DP_USTISL=E.DP_ISLKOD AND E.DP_USTKOD=E.DP_KOD)
   )
   SELECT TOP 374 * FROM DEPT
```

Comment: I am using Ms SQL

Comment: I tried that before, but then i am getting : Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "HIER" of recursive query "DEPT".

Comment: You also need to cast the anchor value of Hier. I have changed my answer. Please check.

Comment: Sorry, i did not apply for the line before union, now problem solved, thanks a lot !!